# JSON deserialization nested square brackets

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize the response from /delta in the Dropbox Core API. The response looks like this:

```
{
  "entries": [
    [
      "/foo.dbf", 
      {
        "bytes": 226822, 
        "client_mtime": "Thu, 26 Sep 2013 23:21:50 +0000", 
        ...
      }
    ], 
    [
      "bar.dbf", 
      {
        "bytes": 147, 
        "client_mtime": "Thu, 26 Sep 2013 23:21:49 +0000", 
        ...
      }
    ],
    ...
  ] 
}
```

I believe the problem is the nested set of square brackets. The innermost ones contain an array consisting of a string and an object. I'm not sure how to represent that in my C# classes.

I've tried representing "entries" as:

```
[DataContract]
public class Delta
{    
    [DataMember(Name="entries")]
    public DeltaInfo[] Entries { get; internal set; }
}
```

and "DeltaInfo" as:

```
[DataContract]
public class DeltaInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Path { get; internal set; }

    [DataMember]
    public PathInfo MetaData { get; internal set; }
}
```

While I end up with the expected number of DeltaInfo objects in my Entries array, both Path and MetaData are null in all of the DeltaInfo objects.

I think my problem is that "entries" doesn't really contain an array of DeltaInfo objects, but rather an array of arrays containing a path and metadata, and I'm not sure how to represent that in my code.

Answer (score 2):

An opening bracket '[' signifies the beginning of a list. Two opening brackets should correspond to a list of lists. The structure would look like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class Delta
{
    [DataMember(Name="entries")]
    public List<List<DeltaInfo>> entries { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DeltaInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Path { get; internal set; }

    [DataMember]
    public PathInfo MetaData { get; internal set; }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, that's not working for me. What I end up with are inner lists with two DeltaInfo items in them, both of which have null for their properties. That implies that the deserializer is seeing both the string and the PathInfo, neither of which it can successfully deserailize to a DeltaInfo. Your earlier suggestion of a List<List<object>> seems like it would be the right approach, except that trying to deserialize to an object throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was not so much the nested arrays as the fact that the innermost array contains multiple types. In the end, I'm using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize the json as a dictionary and constructing the objects myself.